# Is Visual Studio ready for a 4K screen as of June 2014?

Tags: visual-studio

Has anyone any real experience of "Microsoft stack programming" on a 4K screen? Is VS usable or are buttons tiny and annoying? Or the properties editor insanely small? How about other tools, web browsers? etc. etc.

Is is safe to move to 4K yet as a programmer on Windows?

Comment: Nothing new under the sun, "retina" displays have been around for quite a while already.  No problems with VS, hopefully you don't need to use any [Adobe software](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Hans, you could summarise Scott's blog post and stick an answer below and I'll accept it. It seems that while VS and Office are OK, I'll give it another year.

Comment: It's not opinion based. The UI components either scale or they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a really good article covering High-DPI-Support of various programs: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx

According to him, both the Desktop itself (in Windows 8.1) and Microsoft software (he mentions Visual Studio and Office).

> Visual Studio 2013 looks great. Fonts are well-sized, and while the icons aren't high-res (retina) they still look ok. All the Dialog boxes and menus work as they should.

That does not mean that it will never be painful to have a high-dpi screen. Adobe seems to be really bad at high dpi (although I think at least Photoshop has a new high-dpi mode which works really well)

> I am shocked at how bad Adobe stuff looks on a high-dpi display. Just flip a coin, chances are it's gonna be a mix of small and large.

Dropbox is also mixing different scales (which makes it look really crappy), but GitHub (which is obviously in every way superior), looks amazing.